# opengl: Trouble setting up viewport and glortho

Tags: opengl, 3d

I am trying to setup my OpenGL views for some texture rendering. Following some advice on the forum, I set up my viewport and ortho matrix as follows:

First I try to compute the screen width and height that I can use while maintaining the aspect ratio of my image:

```
void resize(int w, int h)
{
    float target_aspect_ratio = image_width / image_height;
    width = w;
    height = (int)(width / target_aspect_ratio + 0.5f);
    if (height > h) {
        height = h;
        width = (int)(height * target_aspect_ratio + 0.5f);
    }       

    off_x = (w - width)/2.f;
    off_y = (h - height)/2;
    // I want to center my image. So I have these offsets 
    glViewport(off_x, off_y, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Now when I want to render my texture I do:

```
void paint()
{
    // texture binding etc.
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(0, 0); 
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(width, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(width, height);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(0, height);
}
```

However, this does not show the image as expected. It does not maintain the aspect ratio as I size the screen. It is almost like the glViewport has no effect and I can verify this function gets called every time my window is resized.

**Update:**

It is strange. Almost as if these calls have no effect. I even did something as:

```
_off_x = _off_y = 0;
_width = 500;
_height = 500;
```

So I expected the viewport to be lower left box of my screen but the image is being drawn as before basically using the whole screen as the viewport.

**Update 2:**

Ok, so if I call

```
glViewport(_off_x, _off_y, _width, _height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, _width, 0, _height, 0, 1);
```

in my paint events, it works as expected! However, I thought it was enough to put this in the resize event handler.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Seems like the new QOpenGLWidget is buggy and overrides the projection matrix and viewport somewhere between the resize and paint calls. I switched to the old QGLWidget and it seems to work as expected...

Answer (score 1):

Before start drawing, you need to switch your Matrix mode to GL_MODELVIEW. You don't need to set your projection matrix inside your render function at each frame.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Here is a detailed analysis that I wrote about glMatrixMode() function modes :
[OpenGL glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) vs glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804087/opengl-glmatrixmodegl-projection-vs-glmatrixmodegl-modelview/29804519#29804519)

Comment: I tried this as well and it has the same effect. :/ The problem seems to be that QOpenGLWidget is undoing the setup somewhere in its code.